# Snake identification

Tags: animal-identification, snakes

I caught this snake in the Dolomites in Northern Italy, in a high-ish (750m) gorge that was lush and heavy with vegetation.

I think, from the description and photos, that it’s a [Western Whip Snake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_whip_snake), but given they grow up to 150cm it is a young specimen.

Can anyone confirm this, or suggest a different species?

[image]

Comment: From [The 18 Types of Snakes That Live in Italy](https://birdwatchinghq.com/snakes-of-italy/) the Smooth Snake seems to be a fit – "On the top of the head is a dark marking which is often in the shape of a crown". But I don't know for sure.

Comment: ...but the body markings look more like the rare Walser Viper.

Comment: @WeatherVane smooth snake is a possibility. I thought it was a slow worm at first, it was that smooth. It was well outside of the known range of the Walser Viper.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would have said the light coloured marking was in the crown shape in OP's photo. Vipers also have very characteristic heads and thick necks. Definitely Colubrid I think.

Comment: I have to ask... what are the white and black specks on your fingernails?  There are none on your fingers, which makes it even more of a mystery!  Really bad nail polish removal technique?  Work as a commercial painter?  Lasting side-effect from too many snake bites?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket glitter nail varnish.

Comment: Ah, you tricked me! When I saw the broken nails, I didn't think glitter nail varnish! :)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket It’s not my usual look. We were on a Scouts trip and the young people needed occupying.

Comment: Haha... I've heard of leaders coming back with their hair and nails looking nothing like when they left!

Answer (score 2):

I think (with little to no expertise in this) that you are correct in your ID of [Western or Green Whip Snake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_whip_snake) (*Hierophis viridiflavus*).

I find snakes difficult as there is so much variation in the patterns of the scales. In the case of the green whip snake, these can be anything from almost no pattern, just blackish to vivid yellow/white blotches/bars.

However, a search of iNaturalist seems to confirm the ID, with [a very similar photo](https://uk.inaturalist.org/observations/60010339), as well as [several more](https://uk.inaturalist.org/taxa/73823-Hierophis-viridiflavus/browse_photos) that point in the same direction. Many of the photos show the same whitish ring around the top of the head and a gradation of patterns from the head along the body.